# Laravel, sending a param through route call when route is listed in an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I currently have menu items being built in an array, and I'm trying to figure out how to properly send a param through two of the menu items so that I can use a single route and controller method. The goal is to have two links, one for Download One and one for Download Two, each with their own "fileType" param.

If I send the value "One" then it downloads one file, another if it sends the value "Two"

WIth my route call structured this way, how can I attach a unique param value to each link and grab it appropriately in the controller?

menu blade:

```
return [

    'downloads' => [
        ['name' => 'Download 1', 'route' => 'file.download.test'],
        ['name' => 'Download 2', 'route' => 'file.download.test']
    ]

]
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'download'], function () {

    Route::get('testDownload/{fileType}', 'Files\downloadController@testDownload')
        ->name('files.download.test');
});
```

Controller:

```
public function testDownload($fileType){

    if($fileType === 'one'){
        $file_name = 'Test1.xlsx';
        $file_path = storage_path("files/{$file_name}");
    }elseif($fileType === 'two'){
        $file_name = 'Test2.xlsx';
        $file_path = storage_path("files/{$file_name}");            
    }

    return \Response::download($file_path);
}
```

Comment: You could add a 'param' element to your array. So when you create the link, take the 'param' element and add it to your route.

Comment: @pacoCham if I add that to just these two array elements, I wouldn't need to add it to any others so that may be a good option. Just ```'param' => 'One'``` and then the route would be ```'testDownload/{param}``` right?

Comment: Yes, if your menu has many other options where you don't need the 'param' element you could check if is set or any other validation method